# What should I do if I have a huge [homebrew-review] question that I need to break into smaller parts?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, homebrew

After asking [Is this variant of the Armorer Artificer balanced compared to the existing subclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/211035/is-this-variant-of-the-armorer-artificer-balanced-compared-to-the-existing-subcl), which offered a wide range of options to choose from, I was informed that it simply had too much content. After this, I broke off a smaller chunk of the content, and it still got downvoted (not as much, though, and it mostly stopped once I transcribed the text from the image). The problem is that if I ask a separate question for each weapon, I'm left with lots of questions (which will crowd the "new questions" page) that take time to write. This might also cause me to get flagged for spamming questions (I don't know how the system works). How should I get a homebrew character option of this size analyzed?

Note: I don't have access to most other RPG forums (RPG.net, Reddit, and GitP are all blocked).

Answer (score 7):

If it's a homebrew feature that's so expansive it can't even fit in a question here, I suggest that what you need is to do your own playtesting rather than ask us. I wrote about similar recently here in the context of [review for an entire game system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12476/1204).

Content reviews here are particularly good for taking a specific feature and giving detailed notes on it—e.g. detailed examination of one character feature—or taking a broader picture and giving broader notes—e.g. assessment of a broad class and any major issues that stand out about it.

I think if a piece of content is so large it's straining our model, it's also going to strain our capacity to review it in any meaningful sense. A variant that large is going to have *so much* going on, there will just be *so many* different things to review and assess and *so many* variables to take into account. We can point out, like, a few things here and there, but we can't reasonably approach a comprehensive review. It would reach the point of even [breaking our Q&A model](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) such that nobody could approach a comprehensive answer. There's just too much *stuff.* Breaking it up piecemeal isn't going to work so well either because then we're not evaluating it in the context of the bigger picture.

What you need to do is instead do some legwork here: you've written the class, now you need to play it and test it, and compare it with other features to make sure  you're on the right track, and take note of any problems that come up, and try to fix them. What you can  then do is if you come across **specific issues** you're having trouble resolving with specific features as surfaced by playtesting and research, come to us and ask about those specific things you're running into and how to resolve them.

Playtesting is an *incredibly* rich vein of feedback that will make all kinds of issues stand out *very* fast, and they'll be issues you can work to identify and solve. We can help you with that process, but this will be the kind of thing where the benefit you get out *and* our capacity to help you will be proportionate to the work you put into playtesting effectively and into attempts to solve the problems yourself.

Comment: In this particular case, it’s 3rd party content from DM’s Guild, not homebrew, but I don’t think that distinction changes the calculus of your guidance here.

Comment: Oh huh. I figured from being a homebrew-review it'd be, you know, review of their homebrew. I missed that first line of the quetsion. I guess it's review of someone else's homebrew?

Comment: Yeah, same user as this Q&A: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12573/62294